# Only able to import small number of photos from iPhone to Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, photos

I'm trying to import all photos from my iPhone to my MacBook. The iPhone shows there are 1,879 photos ("All photos" album). Connecting the iPhone to the Mac using a USB cable and using Image Capture. IC only shows 539 photos available for import. I've also tried importing using Lightroom, which only sees the same 539 photos.

Any ideas?

[image: iPhone]
[image: Image Capture]

Comment: Have you gone to Albums > Recently Deleted to make sure it has been emptied.  I'm not sure, though, if images in this album are counted towards the total.

Comment: Thanks but "Recently Deleted" album is empty. I can see photos on the iPhone that simply no not appear is Image Capture (or any other tool I've tried).

Comment: Do you have iCloud Photo Library, My Photo Stream and/or iCloud Photo Sharing enabled? (Settings > iCloud > Photos)

Comment: Yes, iCloud Photo Library and iCloud Photo Sharing are turned on. Do you consider this something that could cause the problem?

Comment: Noticed the 'Optimise iPhone Storage' option was enabled and when changing it to 'Download and Keep Originals' was presented with a message that there's not enough space on the iPhone. I'm guessing the optimise versions of the photos do not appear when trying to export from the iPhone.

Comment: Looks like I've have to download all photos from iCloud instead. For future ref: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204055

Comment: I've got the same issue, and came up with the same hypothesis about the cause. If we are correct, then there might be another solution: turning on "iCloud Photo Library" on the *Mac* would presumably cause the photos to be downloaded. However, my existing library on my Mac exceeds my current iCloud plan, so this will involve upgrading my plan and paying a larger monthly fee in perpetuity. I'm also not confident this won't end up with all the photos that *are* already on the Mac being re-uploaded to iCloud as duplicates.

Comment: Did you try downloading your photos from the iCloud web site? Was importing them into the Photos app afterwards straightforward? Did it auto detect duplicates correctly?